# Validation Message doesn't show for model as property in viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i've been struggling with Model validation message in asp.net

I've got a model used by a viewmodel.
I want my view to display validation errors if users don't fill required fields.

My ModelState.IsValid is false when required fields are not fill (expected behaviour) but i can't see 
any error message

My Model Class :

```
public class Model
{
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Adress is required.")]
        public string Adress { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel Class:

```
public class ViewModel
{
        [Required]
        public Model SelectedModel { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set;}
}
```

My Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ViewModel vm)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    bool result = *DatabaseStuff*
                    if(result == true)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return View();
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index",vm);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

My View

```
@model ViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h4 class="box-title">ViewModel Form</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedModel.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedModel.Name, null, "SelectedModel_Name",new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedModel.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @data_valmsg_for = "SelectedModel_Name" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedModel.Adress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedModel.Adress, null, "SelectedModel_Adress",new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedModel.Adress, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @data_valmsg_for = "SelectedModel_Adress" })
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="box-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success pull-right" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should not use RedirectToAction but only return View with current model. Like your catch.

Comment: And also I think model validation is not nested by default. It work only for first view model.

Comment: RedirectToAction doesn't change anything because i'm using it for others model and the validation message is displayed when needed.

ModelValidation is working fine, when Name or Adress field ModelState.IsValid == false.

We can watch ModelStateDictionnary and it actually contain the error.

Comment: @daremachine You were right about the return View. but it's weird that redirectToAction display validation message for model but not for a model in a viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you should return View when the ModelState is invalid.

- Return View doesn't make a new requests, it just renders the view
  without changing URLs in the browser's address bar.
- Return RedirectToAction makes a new request and the URL in the browser's
  address bar is updated with the generated URL by MVC.

  ```
      try
      {
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
              bool result = *DatabaseStuff*
              if(result == true)
              {
                  return RedirectToAction("Index");
              }
              else
              {
                  return View();
              }
          }
          return View();
      }
  ```

Comment: It solved my problem, perhaps i still don't understand why RedirectToAction display validation message when i use a Model and doesn't display validation message when i use a Model in a ViewModel.